# Netlogo ERROR - DISTANCE expected input to be an agent but got the number 0 instead

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create home ranges for 3 types of hosts for a model that aims to simulate the movement of ticks across a landscape based on the presence of three host-types.

Using some code that was described in a previous post I created the following code. When I run the model I eventually get the following error message:

**DISTANCE expected input to be an agent but got the number 0 instead.**

Any help with the issue is greatly appreciated.

**to-go**

```
  if ((week-id = 13) or (week-id = 25) or (week-id = 33))
  [ask patches
    [sprout-mice 2
      [set color gray
       set shape "mouse side"
       set size 0.5
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
    ]
  ]

  if week-id = 17[
    let total-deer count deer
    ask n-of (total-deer / 2) patches
    [sprout-deer 1
      [set color brown
       set shape "deer"
       set size 1
        setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
    ]
   ]

  if week-id = 17[
    let total-raccoons count raccoons
    ask n-of (total-raccoons) patches
    [sprout-raccoons 1
      [set color black
       set shape "wolf 2"
       set size 0.5
       setxy random-xcor random-ycor]
    ]
  ]

  mice-mortality
  ;print (count mice)

  if (week-id = 40)
  [deer-mortality]
  ;print(count deer)

  if (week-id = 45)
  [raccoon-mortality]
  print (count raccoons)


 ask deer
  [deer-move]
 ask raccoons
  [raccoons-move]
 ask mice
  [mice-move]
```

**the submodels:**

```
to deer-move
  right random 50
  left random 50
  forward 1
end

to raccoons-move
  ifelse distance home-patch > 10
  [face home-patch]
  [right random 90
    left random 90]
  forward 1
end

to mice-move
  ifelse distance home-patch > 2
  [face home-patch]
  [right random 90
    left random 90]
  forward 1
end
```

Comment: If you don't set `home-patch` to anything the default value will be 0 so `distance home-patch` will give you that error.  In the code you posted, it isn't referenced except in the `raccoons-move` and `mice-move` procedures.

Comment: Jasper,
Thank you!
In the original set-up procedures, I set the home-patch for each host to patch-here. But I realize now that I did not add that same line of code for the new hosts that are born later in the program.